# getEntityRecords in Gutenberg returns null despite there are existing objects

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg

i've been struggling with such a problem for a while - I can't get getEntityRecords query to work properly. It returns null no matter what.

```
import HotspotSliderCustomProducts from "./selector.js";
import { withSelect } from "@wordpress/data";
import { compose} from "@wordpress/compose";


const Slider = (props) => {
    return (
        console.log(props),
        (
            <div className="test">
                <HotspotSliderCustomProducts {...props} />
            </div>
        )
    );
};

const Temp = compose(withSelect((select) => {
  
    const { getEntityRecords } = select("core");
    const { isResolving } = select("core/data");
    const { hasFinishedResolution } = select("core/data");
    return {
       
        products: getEntityRecords(
            "postType",
            "product",
            { per_page: -1 },
        ),
        isRequesting: isResolving("core", "getEntityRecords", [
            "postType",
            "product",
            { per_page: -1 },
        ]),
        hasFinishedResolution: hasFinishedResolution( "core",'getEntityRecords',  [
            "postType",
            "product",
            { per_page: -1 }
        ]),
    };
    
}))(Slider);
export default Temp;
```

The response i'm getting:

```
Object { products: null, isRequesting: false, hasFinishedResolution: false }
```

While doing the query in browser:

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
0: Object { id: 93, date: "2021-12-05T16:38:41", date_gmt: "2021-12-05T16:38:41", … }
1: Object { id: 29, date: "2021-11-16T19:49:17", date_gmt: "2021-11-16T19:49:17", … }
length: 2
​<prototype>: Array []
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the request to the API that is being made by getEntityRecords has not been completed and so data is **null** until the request returns the results we asked for.

you can verify that by running the query in the console several times, it will be null, and then when the API query is finished, it will return results.

So you need to check if the results are returned, which could be done this way.

```
const isLoading = useSelect((select) => {
        return select('core/data').isResolving('core', 'getEntityRecords',  [
            'postType', 'product'
        ]);
     });

if (isLoading) {
        return <h3>Loading...</h3>;
    }

return (......);
```

Here you can find more info about it https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/data-basics/2-building-a-list-of-pages/